# Pythonでテキストから奇数行をリストにしたい

Tags: python, テキストファイル

以下のようなテキストの奇数行(英語の部分)のみを取り出してそれぞれ、同じリストの別の要素として収めたいです。どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

```
a double line
二列
a far cry from 
～とはほど遠い
a walk of life
職業
abandon
～を捨てる
・・・
・・・
・・・
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

source = 'english_words.txt'

with open(source, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()


english_words = re.findall('[a-z]+', data)
ja = re.findall('\n.*\n',data)

jp_meanings = []
for word in ja:
    m = re.sub('\n','',word)
    jp_meanings.append(m)

words_dict = dict(zip(english_words,jp_meanings))

print(jp_meanings)
```

現在のコードはこんな感じです。re.findallでは熟語の空白で要素がかわってしまい、うまくいかなかったので、行ごとに読み込むことにしました。

Comment: 奇数行を取り出す処理については `open('english_words.txt').read().splitlines()[0::2]` としても良いかと。

Comment: @metropolis 質問への回答はコメントではなくぜひ個別の回答として投稿してください。 - 関連メタ: [コメントで回答する理由を教えてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

行毎に処理するだけなら正規表現は不要ですね。以下のようにできます。
(ついでに前後の空白も削除しておきます。ちなみにsplitlines()は改行コード混在もOKです)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
source = 'english_words.txt'

with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    english_words = [l.strip() for i, l in enumerate(data) if ((i%2) == 0)]
    jp_meanings = [l.strip() for i, l in enumerate(data) if ((i%2) != 0)]

words_dict = dict(zip(english_words,jp_meanings))

print(data)
print(english_words)
print(jp_meanings)
print(words_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

ファイルから奇数行だけ抽出する原始的な方法を示します。もっと華麗な方法があるのかもしれませんが。

```
>>> file = open("c:\\temp\\test.txt","r")
>>> number_of_line = 1
>>> line = file.readline()
>>> while line:
...     if number_of_line %2 == 1:
　　　　　　★2で割って１余る場合に出力
...             print(line)
...     number_of_line += 1
...     line = file.readline()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

皆さんがいくつか回答しておられますが、私も作ってみたので、載せておきます。
かなり原始的ですが、while分でループして追加しているだけです。
少し追記した点として、改行コードが混在してもいいように、改行コードを統一しています。

```
import re

source = 'test.txt'
with open(source, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()
data = re.sub(r'\r\n|\r|\n', '\n', data)
array = data.split("\n")
english_words = []
jp_meanings = []
i = 0
while i < len(array):
    english_words.append(array[i])
    jp_meanings.append(array[i+1])
    i += 2
words_dict = dict(zip(english_words,jp_meanings))
print(words_dict)
print(english_words)
print(jp_meanings)
```